# Why doesn't my awk one-liner work when I call it from Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, awk, qsub

I have no problem using the following command of AWK as a stand alone command,
without any error:

```
$ awk '$9 != "NTM" && $9 != ""' myfile.txt  | less -Sn
```

But when I apply them inside Perl's script for [qsub](http://www.doesciencegrid.org/public/pbs/qsub.html) (i.e. running job in linux cluster) command, like this:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Carp;
use File::Basename;

my $path = "/mypath/"; 
my @files = glob($path."*.txt");

foreach my $file ( @files ) {
print "$file\n";
    wy $base = basename($file,".fc-gn_".$type);
    my $nn = $path.$base.".out";

print "$file $nn\n";

    open PIPE, "| qsub" or die $!; 
    print PIPE <<EOF;
#!/bin/sh 
#PBS -N CLEAN
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=2 
#PBS -r n 

awk '$9 != "NTM" && $9 !=""' $file > $nn


EOF

}
```

It gave the following error

```
awk: cmd. line:1:  != "NTM" &&  !=""
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ syntax error
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Putting a `"\"` character before all of your `"$9"` variables will fix it. They're being parsed by Perl itself.

The following script:

```
print <<EOF;
awk '$9 != "NTM" && $9 !=""' $file > $nn
EOF
```

outputs:

```
awk ' != "NTM" &&  !=""'  >
```

but:

```
print <<EOF;
awk '\$9 != "NTM" && \$9 !=""' \$file > \$nn
EOF
```

outputs:

```
awk '$9 != "NTM" && $9 !=""' $file > $nn
```

However, since you want `$file` and `$nn` to be interpreted by Perl, the actual line should be:

```
awk '\$9 != "NTM" && \$9 !=""' $file > $nn
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the backslash solution, or make it more visually appealing by using:

`print <<'EOF'`

(and no backslash), also if you like Perl, you might want to give a shot at [gearman](http://www.danga.com/gearman/), it's really cool.

Comment: Removing the semicolon doesn't have any effect on the behavior in my perl version (5.10) - it still puts in blanks for the $9 variables. What version are you running?

Comment: Sorry, strike that, I forgot the single quotes around the EOF. But now you have a different problem, the $file and $nn are *not* being interpreted by perl as they should be.

Comment: ah right, I didn't look carefully enough, you have to backslash some of it then if you want to keep it in one block